# Fatal error: Class 'SolrClient' not found

Tags: php, solr

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/solr.examples.php) to run solr using php. However I came across the above error. I looked into the [SolrClient Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.solrclient.php), but have no idea how to use it.

Is there a step by step guide for this?

Answer (score 5):

Please run the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
sudo pecl install -n solr
```

Please add extension in php.ini file

```
sudo echo "extension=solr.so" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Please create solr.ini file in  `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/` and add `extension=solr.so` in that file.

or run this command in terminal

```
sudo echo "extension=solr.so" > /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/solr.ini
```

and restart apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

PHP-SOLR client is installed and ready to use.. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are working in Ubuntu Nginx and php-pfm then try this.

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
sudo pecl install -n solr
```

Create solr.ini file

```
sudo echo "extension=solr.so" >/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/solr.ini
sudo echo "extension=solr.so" >/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/solr.ini
```

Restart Nginx and php-fpm

```
sudo restart php5-fpm
sudo service nginx restart
```

Answer (score 1):

in Debian Linux :

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libpcre3-dev php5-dev
sudo pecl install -n solr
sudo echo "extension=solr.so" >/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/solr.ini
sudo echo "extension=solr.so" >/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/solr.ini
sudo echo "extension=solr.so" >/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/solr.ini
sudo echo "extension=solr.so" >/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/solr.ini

sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS, execute the following commands:

1. Install the dependencies:

> yum install curl-devel libxml2-devel

2. Install solr module

> pecl install solr

3. Add solr.so extension to php.ini

> "extension=solr.so"

4. Restart Apache:

> systemctl restart httpd.service